# why tooltip not display with validation in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation, jquery-mobile

I validate my form using jquery  validate .It is working fine .
http://jsfiddle.net/cRew4/2/
When you change focus one field to and another it gives error.
Now I will implement tooltip in that,so I add tittle in all input field as example **"title="title""** it show tooltip but it removed validation of that field.Instead of showing error it show title of the input field. why ? 
http://jsfiddle.net/cRew4/3/

```
$("#commentForm").validate();
  $(document).tooltip();

<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" title="title" type="text" required/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
      <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I need it show tooltip when there is mouse over on the field .but it show validation error when user fill incorrect value intead of tooltip message

Comment: When should tooltip appear?

Comment: I need both tooltip and validation..if user mouse over it show tooltip .but when it fill incorrect value it show correct validate message not tooltip title

Comment: If your question formatting is improved, you should keep it like that. This helps others to read your questions clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validate takes title by default.

So, you must add `ignoreTitle` arguement to it.

**JS**

```
$(document).tooltip();
$("#commentForm").validate({
    ignoreTitle: true
});
```

The documentation mentions it, look here : http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cRew4/7/)**

Comment: @user3665790 : Glad to help... But keep the comment about editted posts in your mind next time. And don't forget to accept the answer if your problem is solved :P